# NodeJs how to write to a file

Tags: node.js, bittorrent

I'm trying to write some data I got from the internet to a file using NodeJS, but all I get is:

```
1fef bfbd 0800 0000 0000 0203 efbf bdef  
bfbd 63ef bfbd 7061 efbf bd2c efbf bdef  
bfbd 6ddb b66d efbf bdef bfbd 7edb b66d  
dbb6 6ddb b66d efbf bdef bfbd 7c7b efbf  
bdef bfbd 3367 26ef bfbd 46ef bfbd 5f2b  
...
```

What I use is request and fs.

```
request(  
    { method: 'GET'  
    , uri: url  
    }  
  , function (error, response, body) {  
    fs.writeFile(torrentFilePath, body, function(err) {  
    if(err) {  
        console.log(err);  
    } else {  
        console.log("The file was saved!");  
    }  
});
```

It's a `.torrent` file I'm trying to download, so I guess it could have some funny characters and that might be the problem? or am i wrong.

Comment: Did you try to open it with torrent program?

Comment: yes i have tried to open in a torrent program. but that does not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encoding your buffer like:

`buffer = new Buffer(body, 'base64');`

`fs.writeFile(torrentFilePath, buffer, function(err) { ... });`

Comment: i still got the hex looking "text" it's just some other charecters, now i get:  
72ef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 69ef bfbd efbf  
bd01 7fef bfbd 5bef bfbd 155b 45ef bfbd  
5bef bfbd 75ef bfbd 0d48 efbf bd17 efbf  
bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 61ef bfbd 2e58... it looks like it writes the buffer and not the string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding the buffer as binary?

```
var b = require('bncode');
var dataToWrite = Buffer.from(b.encode(body), 'binary');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```